# How to manage ghci from C++?

Tags: c++, function, haskell, terminal

I have a .hs file in which there is a Haskell function. My C++ program is supposed to run ghci, call the function, then write the output to a text file, then exit ghci. I thought it could be easily done with `system()`, with which I could have been able to menage the terminal, and do all these good things. But when I execute `system("ghci")`, the C++ program pauses and waits for me to be done with Haskelling.

How can I run a Haskell program from C++?

Comment: There should be command line options to call ghci with.  Otherwise you could (I don't know if you actually can or not) compile the Haskell code into an executable and then call that executable from your c++ code.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for this : https://wiki.haskell.org/Calling_Haskell_from_C ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to do...

- If you have a complete Haskell *program*, you can *compile* it using GHC and then run the resulting compiled program like any other program.
- Alternatively, the `runhaskell` command takes the name of a source code file and runs it for you without needing to compile it first. (It still needs to contain a complete, runnable *program* though.)
- If you have a source file containing several functions, you can use `ghc Module.hs -e expression` to run an arbitrary Haskell *expression* in the specified module.
- Finally, you could try compiling the Haskell code into a dynamic library and link it into your C++ code... but that's really, really complicated.
- It's also possible to call GHC as a library... but again, that's very complicated to do.

Comment: Thank you very much! ghc Module.hs -e expression <-- this solved my problem, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Although it isn't exactly easy to link a dynamic Haskell library into a C++ program, I wouldn't say it's “really, really complicated”.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Depends on your skill level. If you're already an expect C++ programmer, it's not that hard I guess. If you're just learning programming for the first time... it's *real* hard!

Answer (score 0):

`ghci` is the interactive repl. Use `ghc` to compile your .hs file to a binary executable. See [the ghc docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using.html#using-ghc).  For example if you have myfile.hs with a main function then running `ghc myfile.hs` will create an executable `myfile`.  Then in your c++ try `system("./myfile")`.